# Snapchat implementation views

Tags: ios, push-notification, xmpp, apple-push-notifications

I have something i have been thinking about and would like to know your views on it. So I have been wondering how snapchat is implemented.

Incase you don't know, Snapchat is instant messaging client for iOS(not sure if android has one). Users chat primarily through pictures and not text. 
Because its an IM thing, it probably has an XMPP server to handle all the communication but here is what i am wondering. Can it be done without an XMPP server? I have thought about it for a long time and I think probably. 
We could use a normal database server to hold the image, and then push the notification to the device as if it were a normal notification with a link to the image in the database server(don't mind the details). 
The second way seems easier to implement with more scope for extending the product functionality.
Maybe I'm missing something. Would love other opinions on this.

I am aware that this is not the type of questions I should be asking and it'll probably be downvoted but I have to ask this, it's been killing me.

Comment: I wouldn't think Snapchat is implemented using XMPP, and you can most certainly implement this using a "normal database". In Snapchat, the image is downloaded to the device, and is "deleted" after a short period, although this deletion is flawed and there actually exists apps in the appstore that can retrieve such images after deletion (at least, it did. Maybe the developers fixed this by now)

Comment: Honestly I'm pretty sure snapchat only uses APNS (apple push service) to push notifications of new messages, which then tells the app to go fetch new messages.  Not really a complex setup